# How do I manage new tab

Tags: java, android

I am making a web browser app on android studio please can anyone tell me how can I manage my new tab. As every time I click on new tab option it opens a new activity, but I can't navigate between the open tabs. How to do that?

Comment: Using WebView? Forget it, webviews can't handle tabs.

Comment: then any other way

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to use the **WebView** control then you will not succeed. WebViews do not manage more than one opened "tab". More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView